# Undo.RecordObject doesn't save my ScriptableObject back on the disk (doesn't SetDirty it)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, editor

**EDIT:** It *worked*. But now it seems `SetDirty` in `OnValidate` causes my Unity to freeze and I got to kill the app. Definitely not a viable "hack" anymore.

My goal is to have my ScriptableObject saved to disk when I undo the changes made on it by my custom editor.

When I undo, it works but doesn't set it dirty again / doesn't save it on the disk.

That being said my problem may lie deeper as I have to set my ScriptableObject  as dirty for its changes to be registered on disk in the first place.

I resorted to this "hack" using `OnValidate` which works but throws a bunch of:

> SendMessage cannot be called during Awake, CheckConsistency, or OnValidate

```
public class MyBuild : MonoBehaviour
{

}

[CreateAssetMenu] // Create one, place it in a Resources folder and name it "MyTemplates"
public class TemplatesData : ScriptableObject
{
    public List<Template> Templates = new List<Template>() { new Template() };
    public void OnValidate()
    {
        // Called when modified, when the code recompiled or when undo/redo happened.

        // Did this so Undoing would also set it dirty and save it to the disk. It doesn't on its own.

        // Works but throws a bunch of warnings
        EditorUtility.SetDirty(this);
        AssetDatabase.SaveAssets();
    }
}

[System.Serializable]
public class Template
{
    public Vector3 Position;
}

[CustomEditor(typeof(MyBuild))]
public class MyBuildEditor : Editor
{
    private TemplatesData MyTemplates;

    private void Awake()
    {
        MyTemplates = Resources.Load<TemplatesData>("MyTemplates");
    }

    public override void OnInspectorGUI()
    {
        MyBuild myBuild= (MyBuild)target;

        base.OnInspectorGUI();

        if (GUILayout.Button("Save to templates"))
        {
            Undo.RegisterCompleteObjectUndo(MyTemplates, "Saved info to templates");

            // Typically I'll edit the matching one but you get the idea
            MyTemplates.Templates[0].Position = MyBuild.transform.position;

            EditorUtility.SetDirty(MyTemplates);
            AssetDatabase.SaveAssets();
        }
    }
}
```

I'm currently using Unity 2018.1.

Comment: You described your problem but not what you are trying to do. To fix your freezing problem, you need to explain what you are doing

Comment: When undoing, it doesn't set my SO as dirty thus doesn't save it back to disk. I'll update my question to make it clearer.

Comment: I had the same issue when modifying the Scriptable Object's properties via OnSceneGUI > Handles method > set property via code (not just when undoing the changes, rather when moving the handle is anyway). I didn't have this issue with other types of objects, I suspect it's because the properties are not on the component doing the OnSceneGUI. So I need to use EditorUtility.SetDirty followed by the Undo.RecordObject. I suppose that when properties are on the component itself, it gets marked as dirty automatically. Since you got an answer to the original question, maybe you self-reply and accept?

Comment: @hsandt Since I asked this long ago and kinda out of the loop, if you feel more comfortable doing it than me, please go ahead and I'll validate.